# What is a "complete secret"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> “Good afternoon, Harry,” said Dumbledore. 
>  Harry stared at him.
>   Then he remembered: “Sir! The Stone! It was Quirrell! He’s got the
>   Stone! Sir, quick —” 
>  “Calm yourself, dear boy, you are a little
>   behind the times,” said Dumbledore. “Quirrell does not have the
>   Stone.” 
>  “Then who does? Sir, I —” 
>  “Harry, please relax, or
>   Madam Pomfrey will have me thrown out.” 
>  Harry swallowed and
>   looked around him. He realized he must be in the hospital wing. He was
>   lying in a bed with white linen sheets, and next to him was a table
>   piled high with what looked like half the candy shop. 
>  “Tokens
>   from your friends and admirers,” said Dumbledore, beaming. “What
>   happened down in the dungeons between you and Professor Quirrell is
>   **a complete secret**, so, naturally, the whole school knows. I believe your friends Misters Fred and George Weasley were responsible
>   for trying to send you a toilet seat. No doubt they thought it would
>   amuse you. Madam Pomfrey, however, felt it might not be very hygienic,
>   and confiscated it.” 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

In the context, ‘a complete secret’ seems to mean ‘an incident already well-known’. But I don’t find any explanation in dictionaries. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence represents a bit of irony on Professor Dumbledore's part.  By  “[it is] a complete secret” he means that what happened is, officially, entirely a secret.   “So, naturally, the whole school knows” suggests that at Hogwarts the deepest secrets are soonest known, because so many are interested both in hearing and telling them.

Comment: Or it means "it is not a secret at all," since the whole school know.

Comment: That is, don't be misled by the context into thinking that "complete secret" means "not a secret". It's a joke. It's SUPPOSED to be a secret. But even though it's supposed to be a secret, everybody knows.

Answer (score 2):

It's meant to elicit a laugh or chuckle. Evidently, gossip flies fast at Hogwarts, as jwpat7 indicated.

As you know, Hogwarts is an academy filled with school-aged children. Like in so many other institutions with children that age, nothing gets kept secret very long. Someone will tell a friend or two, and those friends will go tell a friend or two, and so on, and so on.

In today's parlance, Dumbledore might have said:

> What happened down in the dungeons between you and Professor Quirrell was supposed to be kept secret, but, naturally, **it went viral**, and now the whole school knows.

In the context of the original, the word *complete* doesn't really change the meaning of the sentence at all; it merely acts as an intensifier, much like the word *very* would.

Comment: I can guess that 'open secret' is the match word for the secret.

Answer (score 1):

A complete secret is only known by the direct participant(s) of an event. It you stole an exam  with a friend and cheated on a test, it would be a complete secret if only the two of you know  about it. On the other hand, it would be a "secret" (not a complete one...) if you also told some best friend or person of trust.